# MacMail - POP3 missing email after recreating local account

Tags: mail.app, email

My Macmail stopped checking/sending email so I recreated the account within MacMail. Upon recreating the local account in MacMail, I'm now able to send and receive but...

The emails that were recovered are only beginning 5/4/20. I expected further back. And, sent emails are gone.

Any way we can recover those?

- I setup my MacMail as POP3 (vs. imap).
- My email was in the cloud and I had folders stored locally on my Mac.
- After recreating the account, my local folders for the original account are not found.
- I'm using MacMail to access a 3rd party email provider, not icloud.

Comment: Do you habe a recent backup of your Mac?

Comment: Yes, I have a timemachine backup.